# Regex not working on returned value

Tags: php, regex

So I was learning about regex and stuff today and I got it to work how I wanted it but when I tried to put it to use as part of something to get data from a site, it did not work. Interestingly enough if I echoed the raw html that I was retrieving, then put it into the regex as a string manually, it worked fine. Does anyone know why this would happen?
Here is the code:

```
preg_match_all('/<img src="images\/cms\/trinket\/(.*).png" \/><\/a> 
                <div style="width:85px; font-size:14px; font-weight:bold; 
                 color:#731c08;">(.*)<\/div>/iU', snd('test.php'), 
               $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

snd is a function with curl returning the data which might be causing the problem but I dont know.

snd function:

```
function snd($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://whatever.com/'.$url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1468.0 Safari/537.36');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $result;
}
```

example (newlines added for readability):

```
<div style="width:600px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; text-align:center; position:relative; z-index:1;"> 
<span style="display:inline-block; width:85px; height:100px;"> 
<a rel="includes/itemajax.php?id=789&tab=trinket" class="clue">
<img src="images/cms/trinket/789.png" /></a> 
<div style="width:85px; font-size:14px; font-weight:bold; color:#731c08;">4</div> 
</span>  <span style="display:inline-block; width:85px; height:100px;"> 
<a rel="includes/itemajax.php?id=891&tab=trinket" class="clue">
<img src="images/cms/trinket/891.png" /></a> 
<div style="width:85px; font-size:14px; font-weight:bold; color:#731c08;">3</div> </span>
```

should return: 789,4 and 891,3

Comment: To scrape a site u'r better of with a DOM parser though

Comment: @DarkBee I would but I dont even know how to search for a pattern like this using one

Comment: If you suspect that the problem is with snd function's return value then please post that code.

Comment: regex isn't a good tool for parsing html (in fact, regex *can't* really parse html because html is not a regular language). it will work ok for simple html strings, but you're far better off using an xml/dom parser (this will help save your sanity too).

Comment: @D-Rock I posted the snd function, but I meant it might be a problem with how the data type is being returned or something because as I said it works fine when its a string.

Comment: I suspect, but not sure, that it might have something to do with the fact that you are returning the headers from your curl call as well and not just the html body? Maybe try leaving those out as a test and see what happens.

Comment: @D-Rock didnt change anything, like I said I copied the entire output of this function into a string not just the content.

Comment: Before trying anything, just do a print of the snd $result

Comment: The regex in your sample, and this may just be modified "for the question", but it contains newlines and indentation-spaces. These are matched against in the actual text it's processing. If I copy+paste the regex and remove the escape-characters and fill in text where the matches go - this code works fine. Try adding the `/x` flag to the regex to ignore-pattern-whitespace. If it doesn't work, add sample text to the question that you're looking to match.

Comment: @newfurniturey I tried the /x thing (I assume you put it at the end of the regex with the U and i, and also posted a section of the html I am trying to parse. Honestly though I might just try that dom parser thing because this seems like a really bizarre issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After comparing your regex to the sample-text, it appears that the issue is with "whitespace" in the sample-text itself.

For instance, `img src=` will not match, but if you change it to `img[\s]+src=`, it will.

If you add this change throughout your regex you should end up with:

```
<img[\s]+src="images\/cms\/trinket\/(.*).png"[\s]+\/><\/a>[\s\r\n]+<div[\s]+style="[^"]+">(.*)<\/div>
```

If you want to split the pattern onto multiple lines for readability, you can also use the `x` flag to "ignore pattern whitespace":

```
preg_match_all('/<img[\s]+src="images\/cms\/trinket\/(.*).png"[\s]+\/><\/a>[\s\r\n]+
                 <div[\s]+style="[^"]+">(.*)<\/div>
                /iUx',
               snd('test.php'), $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

Note: I also updated the list of `style` values in the div's attribute to be just `[^"]+` because the full list was rather long and unnecessary; if it's required, you can always add them back.